# ImageButton on the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[When click on the button which is marked as circular line of image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwVbf.png) then next functionality will be happen which is second image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM8OK.png)

Answer (score 0):

is what you want to happen is that when you click the image button that row layer will hide?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layout at runtime using below snippet onClick of button.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
ViewGroup main = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
main.addView(row, 0);
```

R.layout.row is the row which you want to add on click of arrow.
R.id.child_layout will be an empty LinearLayout placeholder in your parent xml in which above row will be added.

You might want to look at various implementation of addView(), as it is overloaded with various parameters.

You can use removeView to remove the view as well.

There is one more option in which you can the add the row as part of layout set its visibility as GONE
e.g.

```
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

And then you register or deregister click listeners.